# Ambiguity in number comparisons (in C)?

Tags: c, comparison, int, ambiguity

I'm not too familiar with programming in C (I've only done a few small projects in the language), however, my professor said something about it's behavior today that left me a bit confused.

What he said was that this code will sometimes not print anything at all (I copied down exactly what was on the board, I believe this is pseudocode for C since "print" is not in C):

```
    int a = ___________;
    int b = ___________;

    if (a < b)
   print (“<“);
    if (a > b)
   print (“>”);
    if (a==b)
   print(“=”);
```

Basically, there is something you could store in those int variables where none of these conditions would be met (the ***_*__*_*** isn't actual code obviously, it just represents that something is there). It doesn't necessarily need to be some int number that fills those blanks...it could be anything in the world (and there can be stuff that happened before this code).

What is it that could fill those blanks and wouldn't produce any result, and why?

p.s - it had something to do with an overflow, undefined behavior, out of bounds error, or something of the like

p.p.s - I have serious trouble believing this professor was mistaken.  He is more knowledgable about programming than anyone I've ever come into contact with.  I'm convinced there is some case where this is true.

Comment: Your professor is wrong.

Comment: probably confusing a remark about floating point comparison there, C Man

Comment: I'm certain it was an int (further, I'm certain he wasn't referring to  NaN).

Comment: `print` is not defined by the Standard, `“>”` is not a proper string (the delimiters are *strange*), and if you invoke UB anything can happen.

Comment: your username is 'The C Man' but you not very familiar with the programming language :p

Comment: I actually just changed my username to my real name...my name starts with a 'C' haha.  Hasn't updated yet!

Comment: pmg: This was pseudocode for C.  Thanks for pointing that out, I just clarified this in my initial code.

Comment: There are two options: 1. Your professor is wrong 2. You missunderstood what he said.

Comment: Andreas: 

1. Is an impossibility.  No way this guy was wrong about C.
2. Highly, highly unlikely since I copied down everything word for word and listened to what he said.

Comment: You did not copy an essential part: The placeholder behind the ints.

Comment: If there is case for `int` where this is true (which there isn't), there should be a case for `short` as well in which case you can loop over all possible values of `a` and `b` and see for yourself that something's always printed.

Comment: I'll ask my professor about this as soon as I can (everyone not believing me has certainly heightened my interest in finding an answer).  Sadly, I won't see him until Tuesday.  If no one has solved this by then, I'll let you guys know on Tuesday what he said.

Comment: short have different semantics, especially they are autopromoted to ints when used together. But with today's hardware he may loop over all ints in a few seconds.

Comment: @drhirsch Looping over all *pair* of ints will take considerable time, even on today's hardware.

Comment: Hmm, that's true. You need a platform with 16 bit ints then :-)

Comment: Did you ever get an answer from your professor?

Answer (score 4):

All that is necessary is for one of the int initialisations to generate a run-time exception. The program will then terminate prior to any of the comparison tests. E.g.

```
int b = *(int *)0;
```

Comment: if the answer is along these lines the _______; can be exchanged for anything, e.g. `int a = callToFunctionThatReturnsIntButSegfaults();`

Comment: or even `int a = 1; exit(0);`

Comment: @murrekatt: very good, but note that for C89 it would need to be `int b = 1; exit(0);`

Comment: Good answer, but I doubt this is what he meant (since he was clarifying it was C specific).

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's the ***_*** part that matters. If the underlined part contains code results UNDEFINED behavior, and the following code with comparisons get *optimized* by a "clever" compiler wrt the undefined behavior, the ultimate behavior of this piece of code is undefined. And not printing anything is a reasonable undefined behavior.

p.s. According to Wikipedia, division by zero results in undefined behavior, although most compilers define it an error. And IIRC signed integer overflow also causes undefined behavior, although again this usually cause runtime exception or even compilation error. So if a and b are declared as

```
int a = 1 / 0;
int b = INT_MAX + 1;
```

the situation your prof describes may occur. But remember, the behavior is undefined, so whatever the compiler chooses the program to behave might be considered conformant with the standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an architecture with int numbers in one's complement, there exist two zeros: One with all bit set to 0 and one with all bit set to 1, aka positive and negative zero. Both zeros should compare equal, but a buggy compiler may not see that so ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For int this is not true, because they have no "special" values.

Comment: Wouldn't the negative zero in one's complement qualify as special?

Answer (score 0):

> p.s - it might have had something to do with an overflow?

I think this is what your professor meant:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    uint8_t a = 100;
    uint8_t b = 200;

    a = a + b; /* a = 300 in your head. This overflows, so 300-256=44 */

    if ( a > b )
    {
        printf("%u > %u", a, b);
    }
    else if ( a < b )
    {
        printf("%u < %u", a, b);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%u == %u", a, b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Specifically, I am using a fixed width 8-bit unsigned integer, which can hold at maximum 8 bits (surprise) which represents 256 as the largest possible integer. You can overflow this field by adding to it an amount that can't be represented in this size, in which case what you're left with is a wrap-around effect.

There is no actual ambiguity in the if comparison logic, since that's actually part of the processor (if translates to one of the comparison / jump instruction combinations). The issue is that you might have programmed it reasonably expecting it to work, not realising that number representations on a computer all have fixed representations. I can't see anything I could put into those registers that would possibly escape all of "less, greater or equal".

Note I've used the C99-introduced fixed size integers for clarity and small number sizes so we can do it in our head.

Comment: He said the professor claimed that this code would sometimes not print anything at all, this code prints "44 < 200"

Comment: Yes, it will. But even with signed types, you're just altering a register. I cannot think of any way you could possibly fail, even if you compared a pointer to an integer since a pointer in a register is just a number. I can only think he must have been trying to make the point about integer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 0, b = 5 / a : divide by zero
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that "there can be stuff that happened before this code"...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{

#define int float

    int a = nanf(NULL);
    int b = nanf(NULL);

    if (a < b)
       printf("<\n");
    if (a > b)
       printf(">\n");
    if (a == b)
       printf("==\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or that you've replaced `print` with a function that doesn't do anything.

Comment: or instead of that `#define` you just `return 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the defintion of `print` is:

```
void
print(const char*) {    
}
```